# Filling in email and password using a button on Microsoft login \w out API

Tags: vb.net

I have been struggling to figure out on how to fill in the email and password on the page and click a button to log into Microsoft, but I cant figure it out. I am very new to VB.net and would like some help to get better at and to learn. so far I have:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load       
   WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://login.live.com/")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim elements = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each element As HtmlElement In elements

        If element.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
            element.InvokeMember("click")

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have tried to use the `GetElementById("").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)`, but I'm having a hard time finding it. Could some one please point me in the right direction or show me some code on how to do this. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to type your username and password automatically, then you may have to take a look on AutoIt. It is a scripting anguage. You can easily do this with built-in functions. There is a COM version for AutoIt. So you can add reference to your vb.net project and import it to your class. And you can easily call almost all useful function from there. Give try. Here is the link 
https://www.autoitscript.com/site/